# Issue with getHelper().enterDragAndLeave() in JFC

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtree

I am using getHelper().enterDragAndLeave() to drag a JTree node from source to destination. The test case runs successfully in sometimes and sometimes it fails to drap and drop the node. Can anyone give me an idea what might be the issue?